# How to call html form fields in vbscript dynamically in a loop

Tags: html, loops, vbscript, asp-classic

So I have an html form created in classic asp that has about 25 check boxes with different labels.  The checkboxes are written to the page via a loop that grabs the label values from a table and each checkbox is named similarly ("decreason1","decreason2","decreason3",ect...) using a loop variable.

I use a vbscript at the end of the page to validate the data on the page before passing with a submit button.   I need to make sure that at least one of the checkboxes is checked before submitting the form.

```
dim i, checkedvalue ;
checkedvalue = false

for i = 1 to 25 
  if document.rtftadd.decreason1.checked = true then
    checkedvalue = true
end if
next
```

I need the "document.rtftadd.decreason1.checked"  to change with the loop to decreason2, decreason3

I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to do this and if you are seeking a validation method prior to form submission then JavaScript may be a better solution.

However, in an effort to address your question using only ASP Server side code for VBScript and considering your question suggest that you do not care which box is selected nor how many are selected then the following code may be a working solution for you.

By looking at all of the elements sent via the form and checking if your form name (without number) exist then this same block of code will work even if you increase or decrease the number of check boxes you are validating for input.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>
<% 
   dim checkedvalue
   checkedvalue = false
   if request("btn1") = "Submit" then
      For each item in request.form   
          if instr(item,"decreason") > 0 then
              checkedvalue = true
          end if
       next
       response.write "Checked Value  = " & checkedvalue & "<br><br>"
   end if
%>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <form method="post" action="index.asp" name="rtftadd">
        <input type="checkbox" name="decreason1"> Box 1<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="decreason2"> Box 2<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="decreason3"> Box 3<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="decreason4"> Box 4<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="decreason5"> Box 5<br> 
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btn1">
   </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```